# I have question about to download 1.5 gb data from google datastore with Threading and fastest way in C#

Tags: download, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I have **Google Datastore** Data of **1.5Gb** (around **800000** entity), it will take around **4000 seconds** to download whole data.

1) is it possible to make it fast?

2) can we compress data with "**accept-encoding: gzip**" while requesting Client API of Google Datastore?

1) I have tried with RunQueryLazily but it will bulk in 300 entity/seconds but it will take 2666 seconds to download whole data but it is not fast.

```
Query queryString = new Query(kindname);
var data = _db.RunQueryLazily(queryString);

foreach (Entity entity in data)

{

....

store in inner class model

....

}
```

Output Result will be Large List of Data.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are looking to get all of your data out faster you should consider parallelizing your query with Cloud Dataflow.  The connector for Dataflow to read from Cloud Datastore exists for both python & java. 
 The list of built-in connectors is at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/.

2) The responses should already be compressed if your request contains 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'.